# What to do when seemingly influential variable is insignificant in linear regression model?

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, p-value

I am working with a model to evaluate the impact of implementing individual prevention measures on property damage. Not only is it my hypothesis that they have a reducing effect on the damage variable (my dependent variable), but also there is a clear difference in mean damage when comparing whether a measure was implemented or not.

Further, I tried to reduce the model to only the dependent variable on one of the measures, but the P-Value still remains insignificant (above 10%).

What am I missing?

Comment: How are your variables measured? And what is your goal with the model?

Comment: Could be all sorts of things - low sample size and/or noisy data leading to low power of the test, but of course, your hypothesis could be wrong, too!

Comment: @fmtcs I am building a model that regresses flood damage (as a ratio of damage over house market value) on the implemented mitigation measures (dummy variable 0|1) controlling for factors such as water height. But no matter how I reduce/add variables, the p-value of the mitigation measures remains insignificant. The only significant variable is the water height. How could it be that there is a clear difference in mean damage between a measure being implemented or not without them being significant in any model.

Comment: @fmtcs the goal of the model is to evaluate the effectiveness of the individual measures on reducing flood damage. and i'm more than convinced that at least one of them will have to have a significant reducing effect. also i didnt find any significant correlation between any of the variables.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @tookja As Christoph said there could be a lot of reasons. When you have for example Y~X1 and X1 is not significant, it basically means what was explained in the response by X1 is expected to be explained by Y~X1 just by chance in a non-acceptable (i.e. too high) proportion of replications of the same sampling and model building process, given the null model of just the intercept. In other words, it's not better than a horizontal line (the model with just an intercept). However, if your sample size is small then maybe your sample just doesn't characterize the true relationship.

Comment: @tookja "How could it be that there is a clear difference in mean damage between a measure being implemented or not without them being significant in any model." : The model can "see" that there's a difference, but it doesn't have enough confidence to tell you that this difference in means isn't just due to chance. A larger sample size provides more confidence in estimates

Comment: Please add new in formation in comments as an edit to the post, not only in comments. Comments are easily overlooked, and can be removed!